# Why am I unable to stop Android BluetoothManager searching for devices?

Tags: java, android

I have an issue where BluetoothManager constantly shows the following message in LogCat, even after device Bluetooth has been turned off.

```
D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
```

This causes a problem when I try to search for new devices, the only way I can stop this is to 'force quit' the app. Please see what I have tried below, I've tried a few other things but nothing seems to work.

```
BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
btManager.getAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
```

Also,

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more code on how you are scanning for the devices?

On the Android Docs for BLE devices : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find

You first need to create a `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` and then you can pass it to the `bluetoothAdapter` to start scan: `bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);` or to stop the scan: `bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);`